# Pandas to parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I am trying to save a pandas object to parquet with the following code:

```
LABL = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
df.to_parquet("/data/TargetData_Raw_{}.parquet".format(LABL))
```

this gives me the error:

```
ArrowTypeError: ("Expected bytes, got a 'float' object", 'Conversion failed for column Pre-Rumour_Date with type object')
```

The pandas dtypes are as follow:

```
0
Announced_Date                  object
Completed_Date                  object
Pre-Rumour_Date                 object
                                object
Lapsed_Date                     object
Target_Company                  object
Bidder_Company                  object
Seller_Company                  object
Deal_Value_USD(_m)              object
Exit_Type                       object
Buy_Type                        object
Sell_Stake_(%)                  object
Buy_Stake_(%)                   object
Months_Held                     object
Private_Equity_House            object
ADATE                   datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: @AnuragDabas it then shows error `TypeError: Object of type 'int64' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Try casting your `object` columns to explicit types with `Series.astype()`.

Comment: I think you might need to convert the last column type from datetime to string to be hemogenous dateframe which is the condition to convert it to parquet

Comment: You can read this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21228#issuecomment-462590774

Comment: This as well, https://github.com/equinor/webviz-config/issues/285

Answer (score 6):

Try: `df.astype(str).to_parquet("/data/TargetData_Raw_{}.parquet".format(LABL))`