# Pandas to_gbq() TypeError "Expected bytes, got a 'int' object

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am using the `pandas_gbq` module to try and append a dataframe to a table in Google BigQuery.

I keep getting this error:

> ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'int' object.

I can confirm the data types of the dataframe match the schema of the BQ table.

I found this post regarding Parquet files not being able to have mixed datatypes: [Pandas to parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826636/pandas-to-parquet-file)

In the error message I'm receiving, I see there is a reference to a Parquet file, so I'm assuming the `df.to_gbq()` call is creating a Parquet file and I have a mixed data type column, which is causing the error. The error message doesn't specify.

I think that my challenge is that I can't see to find which column has the mixed datatype - I've tried casting them all as strings and then specifying the table schema parameter, but that hasn't worked either.

This is the full error traceback:

```
In [76]: df.to_gbq('Pricecrawler.Daily_Crawl_Data', project_id=project_id, if_exists='append')
ArrowTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-74cec633c5d0> in <module>
----> 1 df.to_gbq('Pricecrawler.Daily_Crawl_Data', project_id=project_id, if_exists='append')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_gbq(self, destination_table, 
project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, 
progress_bar, credentials)
   1708         from pandas.io import gbq
   1709
-> 1710         gbq.to_gbq(
   1711             self,
   1712             destination_table,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials)
    209 ) -> None:
    210     pandas_gbq = _try_import()
--> 211     pandas_gbq.to_gbq(
    212         dataframe,
    213         destination_table,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, reauth, if_exists, auth_local_webserver, table_schema, location, progress_bar, credentials, api_method, verbose, private_key)
   1191         return
   1192
-> 1193     connector.load_data(
   1194         dataframe,
   1195         destination_table_ref,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py in load_data(self, dataframe, destination_table_ref, chunksize, schema, progress_bar, api_method, billing_project)
    584
    585         try:
--> 586             chunks = load.load_chunks(
    587                 self.client,
    588                 dataframe,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\load.py in load_chunks(client, dataframe, destination_table_ref, chunksize, schema, location, api_method, billing_project)
    235 ):
    236     if api_method == "load_parquet":
--> 237         load_parquet(
    238             client,
    239             dataframe,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\load.py in load_parquet(client, dataframe, destination_table_ref, location, schema, billing_project)
    127
    128     try:
--> 129         client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    130             dataframe,
    131             destination_table_ref,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py in load_table_from_dataframe(self, dataframe, destination, num_retries, job_id, job_id_prefix, location, project, job_config, parquet_compression, timeout)
   2669                         parquet_compression = parquet_compression.upper()
   2670
-> 2671                     _pandas_helpers.dataframe_to_parquet(
   2672                         dataframe,
   2673                         job_config.schema,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py in dataframe_to_parquet(dataframe, bq_schema, filepath, parquet_compression, parquet_use_compliant_nested_type)
    584
    585     bq_schema = schema._to_schema_fields(bq_schema)
--> 586     arrow_table = dataframe_to_arrow(dataframe, bq_schema)
    587     pyarrow.parquet.write_table(
    588         arrow_table, filepath, compression=parquet_compression, **kwargs,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py in dataframe_to_arrow(dataframe, bq_schema)
    527         arrow_names.append(bq_field.name)
    528         arrow_arrays.append(
--> 529             bq_to_arrow_array(get_column_or_index(dataframe, bq_field.name), bq_field)
    530         )
    531         arrow_fields.append(bq_to_arrow_field(bq_field, arrow_arrays[-1].type))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_pandas_helpers.py in bq_to_arrow_array(series, bq_field)
    288     if field_type_upper in schema._STRUCT_TYPES:
    289         return pyarrow.StructArray.from_pandas(series, type=arrow_type)
--> 290     return pyarrow.Array.from_pandas(series, type=arrow_type)
    291
    292

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.array()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\array.pxi in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\error.pxi in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'int' object
```

Comment: Hi OP, can you provide your sample code for appending a dataframe to a table in Google BigQuery and a sample dataset with schema? This is to properly replicate your use case.

Comment: did you solve it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had this same issue - solved it simply with

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

and doing `to_gbq` on that instead.

Caveat is that all your fields will now be strings...

Comment: Instead of converting all your columns to type 'str', identify the column that's giving you trouble and convert only that one - it probably has mixed data types and that's why you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but a kludgy workaround. I'm having this exact same problem with dataframes which contain columns of the INT64 type. I've found that doing the following works:

```
from io import StringIO
# temporarily store the dataframe as a csv in a string variable
temp_csv_string = df.to_csv(sep=";", index=False)
temp_csv_string_IO = StringIO(temp_csv_string)
# create new dataframe from string variable
new_df = pd.read_csv(temp_csv_string_IO, sep=";")
# this new df can be uploaded to BQ with no issues
new_df.to_gbq(table_id, project_id, if_exists="append")
```

I have no idea why this works. Both dataframes seem to be identical if you look at `df.info()` and `new_df.info()`. I decided to try this after saving the offending dataframe as a csv and uploading it to biquery in that format, which worked.

Note that this specifically happens with INT64 type columns. I'm uploading dataframes generated in the same way that don't contain INT64 values whithout any issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and what had fixed it for me is specifying data types already when reading the data into the dataframe (in my case via read_csv).

```
    data_types = {'program_type':'string','program_number':'int64','program_isan':'string','program_title':'string'}
    df = pd.read_csv(local_file_path, dtype=data_types)
```

When subsequently using pandas_gbq to_gbq to create a table in BigQuery it finally worked. Without specifying via dtype during read_csv I always received this error later down the line when trying to create the BigQuery table.

Answer (score 1):

You can set column_names.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=['{column_name1}','{column_name2}'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue when loading API data to BigQuery and I believe thing this is more efficient to get rid of the Int64_field_0.

```
blankIndex=[''] * len(df)
df.index=blankIndex
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the expected schema of your table in the form of a dictionary like so:
schema= [{'name': 'row', 'type': 'INTEGER'},{'name': 'city', 'type': 'STRING'},{'name': 'value', 'type': 'INTEGER'}]
replace with your values
and then inside the function use table_schema=schema

this function  allows for a schema to be passed. wrong!
this function requires a schema to be passed, but if you don't, a little  snippet will quickly autogenerate one for you.
When the contents down the road don't match the autogenerated schema then it fails like this because the default type is a String and in the first column there was nothing that indicated something else was needed than the default.

workaround alert -> if the row at the top has all the the fields populated chances are it will infer correctly what the schema is and you avoid the error without passing a schema.

This makes the function's behavior to look random and it is what throws people off sometimes.

The first solution works because it makes everything a String and String being the default well....it works
however you end up with a table that you now have to type if you want all your fields to be proper.

Hope it helps.  if so Upvote!

Answer (score 0):

In case there is just one or a few problematic columns, you can also get around it with explicitly specifying the schema in the job config
bigquery.SchemaField("problematic_column", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),

Answer (score 0):

If your file is small enough, I suggest to use `to_gbq` with the option `api_method="load_csv"` (available as of v0.16) so that you don't need to rely on pyarrow.

With this approach, you don't have to cast the full dataframe as `str` upfront which, among other limitations, turns missing value as `"nan"` in bigquery

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Pandas to push data to Google BigQuery, and in my case, I received this error message:
"pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected bytes, got a 'date' object"

This bug occurs when you are pushing data to a new table, in other words, Pandas will create a new table for you, and apparently some part of that system is unable to correctly transform pandas data types to corresponding BQ types (especially the 'DATE').
I solved this by defining the types myself and providing the *table_schema* parameter.

```
    def push_pd_to_bq(self, df: pd.DataFrame, tabel: str, project: str, mode: str = 'append'):
    df = df.copy()
    df['commit_timestamp'] = pd.Timestamp('now', tz='Europe/Helsinki')
    table_schema = [] # [{'name': 'col1', 'type': 'STRING'},...]
    for col in df.columns:
        if 'object' in str(df[col].dtype):
             table_schema.append({'name': col, 'type': 'STRING'})
        elif 'float' in str(df[col].dtype):
            table_schema.append({'name': col, 'type': 'FLOAT64'})
        elif 'datetime' in str(df[col].dtype):
            table_schema.append({'name': col, 'type': 'TIMESTAMP'})
        elif 'date' in col.lower():
             table_schema.append({'name': col, 'type': 'DATE'})
    df.to_gbq(destination_table=tabel, 
              if_exists=mode, 
              project_id=project, 
              table_schema=table_schema, 
              location='europe-north1')
```